# Why session variable storage reference not new object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue becasue I want to compare my two lists first one will be mofidied and the second will have initial values.

At the begining i create list and clone of it and add it to Session.

```
List<Ranking> ranking = new List<Ranking>();
ranking.Add();//adding items to list
Session["rankingi"] = ranking;
List<Ranking> rankingFromBase = new List<Ranking>(ranking);
Session["rankingFromBase"] = rankingFromBase;
```

And then I want to change first list by editing GridView.

```
List<Ranking> rankingCollection = (List<Ranking>)Session["rankingi"];
 var newSimulationRanking = rankingCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        if (newSimulationRanking != null)
        {
            rankingCollection.Remove(newSimulationRanking);

            newSimulationRanking.name = name;
            newSimulationRanking.age = age;
            rankingCollection.Add(newSimulationRanking);

        }
```

After this when I change a age in first list I received the same change in second List when I do this:

```
List<Ranking> rankingFromBase = new List<Ranking>();
rankingFromBase = (List<Ranking>)Session["rankingFromBase"];
```

What I have to do to get one modified list and the second with initial values?

Comment: You're not storing the list back into the session object after you have modified it.

Comment: What sort changes? I have only one tested row in that list.

Comment: debug it step by step...

Comment: I do this. I have one place at the begining when PostBack I create that 2 variable Session then I operate on first `Session["ranking"]`  and then when I cast a `Session["rankingFromBase"]` I see that `List<Ranking> rankingFromBase` have the same changes like that modified List from `Session["ranking"]`

Comment: You're cloning the list but not cloning *the items that the list contains*. You have two independent lists containing references to the *same* objects. Does the `Ranking` class have some easy means of creating a copy (e.g. a constructor that accepts an existing `Ranking` object)?

Comment: No class `Ranking` does not have any ways of creating copy of that object.